# MySQL COUNT doesn't work properly with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have Zipcodes with IDs 1-100.

The following query returns a count of 1, even though the id in the where-clause doesn't exist:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `Zipcode.count` 
FROM `Zipcode` 
WHERE `Zipcode`.`id` = "22a" LIMIT 1;
```

I believe it is because of the "22a" becoming simply "22" behind the scenes in MySQL. Maybe because MySQL is automatically converting the datatype or somthing?

The following provides a zero count (so it makes a difference if the char "a" is in front or behing the int "22"):

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `Zipcode.count` 
FROM `Zipcode` 
WHERE `Zipcode`.`id` = "a22" LIMIT 1;
```

I want this query to match against the string. If the datatype isn't correct, it shouldn't remove characters, which falsely provides me with an undesired answer. The result should be zero in both cases.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `Zipcode.count`
FROM `Zipcode`
WHERE CAST(`Zipcode`.`id` AS CHAR) = "22a"
```

It will [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) datatype of id to a CHAR, so it won't convert '22a' to 22.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `Zipcode.count` FROM `Zipcode` WHERE `Zipcode`.`id` = 22a LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this. Make a note that you'll only ever get a maximum result of one due to the LIMIT clause being set to 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS zipCodeCount 
FROM `Zipcode` 
WHERE `id` = "22a" 
LIMIT 1;
```